# How to display values from SQLite database in table format

Tags: android, sqlite

I have created SQLite database application which contain fields `id`, `Name`, `Con`. I want to display value in table format. I have used arraylist to hold value. It only displays value in row format. Please help me, how I can display value in table format?

Comment: Show what you have done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using he [GridVIew](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html).

[This](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-gridview-layout-tutorial/) and [this](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-gridview-example/) ink also has some grid view tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

Bind ArrayList in Listview by using BaseAdapter or ArrayAdapter ...and for looks like Table format.. make a custom XML.. and make a view by Inflate..

Answer (score 0):

```
Try using table layouts with textview in a tablerow tag..
like..
<TableLayout>
<TableRow>
<TextView/>
<TextView/>
<TableRow>
<TableLayout>
```